# Mistake calculating $\int \frac {\mathrm d x} {\sqrt {(a x + b) (p x + q)} }$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

Yes I know I've asked this question before, but this time it's more specific.

I am still trying to get to grips with the calculation of $\int \dfrac {\mathrm d x} {\sqrt {(a x + b) (p x + q)} }$ (Schaum's *Mathematical Handbook of Formulas and Tables*, 1968).

This is for when $a p < 0$.

The answer is:
$$\dfrac 2 {\sqrt {-a p} } \arctan \left({\sqrt {\dfrac {-p (a x + b) } {a (p x + q) } } }\right) + C$$

My working is using Euler's Substitution of the Third Kind.

$$\sqrt {a x^2 + b x + c} = \sqrt {a (x - \alpha) (x - \beta) } = (x - \alpha) t$$

First express the integrand as:

$$\int \frac {\mathrm d x} {\sqrt {(a x + b) (p x + q) } }= \int \frac {\mathrm d x} {\sqrt {a p \left({x - \left({-\frac b a}\right) }\right) \left({x - \left({-\frac q p}\right) }\right) } }$$

so that $a \gets a p$, $\alpha \gets -\dfrac b a$, $\beta \gets -\dfrac q p$.

Then:

$$x = \dfrac {a p \left({-\frac q p}\right) - \left({-\frac b a}\right) t^2} {a p - t^2} = \dfrac {-a q + \left({\frac b a}\right) t^2} {a p - t^2} = \dfrac {a^2 q - b t^2} {a (t^2 - a p) }$$

This leads to:

$$x - \alpha = \dfrac {a (\alpha - \beta) } {t^2 - a} = \dfrac {a p \left({\left({-\frac b a}\right) - \left({-\frac q p}\right) }\right) } {t^2 - a p}$$

substituting $a \gets a p$, $\alpha \gets -\dfrac b a$, $\beta \gets -\dfrac q p$.

Thus:
$$x - \alpha = \dfrac {a q - p b} {t^2 - a p}$$

Then:

$$\dfrac {\mathrm d x} {\mathrm d t} = \dfrac {2 t a p \left({\left({-\frac q p}\right) - \left({-\frac b a}\right) }\right) } {(a p - t^2)^2} = \dfrac {2 t a (b p - a q) } {(t^2 - a p)^2}$$

Then after some algebra:

$$t = \pm a \sqrt {\dfrac {p x + q} {a x + b} }$$

(Not sure what to do about the $\pm$, I'll figure it out later.)

Putting it all together:

$$\int \frac {\mathrm d x} {\sqrt {(a x + b) (p x + q) } } = \int \frac {\mathrm d t} {\left({\dfrac {a q - p b} {t^2 - a p} }\right) t} \dfrac {2 t a (b p - a q) } {(t^2 - a p)^2}
 = -2 a \int \dfrac {\mathrm d t} {(t^2 - a p) }$$

Hence as $a p < 0$ by hypothesis:

$$\int \frac {\mathrm d x} {\sqrt {(a x + b) (p x + q) } } = -2 a \int \dfrac {\mathrm d t} {(t^2 + (-a p)) }  = -2 a \arctan \dfrac t {\sqrt {-a p} } + C$$

which leads to:
$$= -2 a \arctan {\dfrac {\pm a \sqrt {\frac {p x + q} {a x + b} } } {\sqrt {-a p} } } + C = -2 a \arctan {\sqrt {-\dfrac a p} \dfrac {\sqrt {p x + q} } {\sqrt {a x + b} } } + C$$

(The $\pm$ still needs to be resolved, clearly -- not done that.)

Clearly I'm on the right lines, but the details do not match what we're aiming for.

Can anyone put their finger on what I have done wrong?

Many thanks

Comment: If you are interested in a different method to solve the indefinite integral given in your post, I would like to divert your attention to the solved problem 15.$c$ on pages 89 and 90 of the book Advance Calculus (Schaum’s outline Series). I worked out it as instructed by one of the two methods illustrated in the mentioned book and got the following answer having a sine-inverse term.
$$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{-ap}}\sin^{-1}\left(\dfrac{p\left(ax+b\right)+ a\left(px+q\right)}{aq=bp}\right)+C$$

Comment: @YNK Yes, that's a straightforward result which can be achieved by setting $u = \sqrt {a x + b}$ and getting an integrand in the form $1 / \sqrt {c - u^2}$. Such an evaluation was the subject of a question I raised back in Dec 2020.

Comment: @YNK ... and having checked out that resource, it only gives the special case of $\int \frac {\mathrm d x} {\sqrt {(x + 2) (3 - x)} }$ so not all that much immediate use.

Comment: @YNK ... and has been documented as https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Primitive_of_Reciprocal_of_Root_of_a_x_%2B_b_by_Root_of_p_x_%2B_q/a_greater_than_0,_p_less_than_0 -- done by completing the square.

Comment: Thanks for the information. When I posted my comment, I did mean to divert your attention only to the two methods suggested in the book to solve the mentioned special case and not to the special case itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following calculation is off

$$\dfrac {\mathrm d x} {\mathrm d t} = \dfrac {2 t a p \left({\left({-\frac q p}\right) - \left({-\frac b a}\right) }\right) } {(a p - t^2)^2} = \dfrac {2 t a (b p - a q) } {(t^2 - a p)^2}$$
Instead, it should be
$$\dfrac {\mathrm d x} {\mathrm d t} = \dfrac {2 t (b p - a q) } {(t^2 - a p)^2}$$
Then
\begin{align}
\int \frac {\mathrm d x} {\sqrt {(a x + b) (p x + q) } } 
&= -2 \int \dfrac {\mathrm d t} {(t^2 - a p) }
=-\frac2{\sqrt{-ap}}\tan^{-1}\frac t{\sqrt{-ap}}\\
&= -\frac2{\sqrt{-ap}}\tan^{-1}\frac {a \sqrt {(a x + b) (p x + q) } }{\sqrt{-ap}\ (ax+b)}+C\\
&= \frac2{\sqrt{-ap}} \tan^{-1} {\sqrt {\dfrac {-p (a x + b) } {a (p x + q) } } } -\frac\pi2+ C
\end{align}

Comment: A thousand upvotes.